# Are questions on software on topic

Tags: discussion

Are questions on software on topic?

This question on [writing software](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3054/openoffice-vs-libreoffice-vs-msoffice-for-academic-writing) seems almost identical to questions on [poster](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/software-to-use-for-creating-posters-for-academic-conferences), [illustration](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/software-to-draw-illustrative-figures-in-papers), [notebook](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1085/software-app-for-electronic-research-notebooks), [citation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36/how-do-the-various-citations-management-software-programs-compare), and [data analysis](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/what-are-the-most-common-types-of-software-used-for-data-analysis-by-scientific) software. The citation and data analysis questions were closed. All but the data analysis questions are highly voted.

Answer (score 13):

As I stated [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2993/73), I think software questions are definitely **on-topic**. I think it would fall under the rubric of "Life as a graduate student, postdoctoral researcher, university professor", which is on-topic as per our FAQ.

Comment: I wasn't referring to all software questions, but rather ones that are likely to produce a long list as an answer with each being equally valid.

Comment: @Daniel - [Such questions are already discouraged here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). That being said, I personally judge these questions individually; if it's well-written and useful, go ahead, says I.

Comment: Software is of great interest. The correct answer should be modified to indicate this answer.

Answer (score -3):

Across StackExchanges, asking for recommendations for products is strongly discouraged.

As are long-list questions.

As are questions where there is no one right answer.

These software questions hit all three of those. **Let's close them all.**

Comment: Agree with you on that product recommendations should be discouraged. But specific questions with specific needs should be addressed. For example, http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3054/openoffice-vs-libreoffice-vs-msoffice-for-academic-writing/3058 asks for specific comparison of 3 products for a specific need. If the answers start to go beyond what the OP asks/needs, those answers should be moderated. 

So in general all software related questions should be handled, separately on case-by-case basis. Should not be banned all the way.

Comment: The problem is that I am not sure it is the question, or how we answer them. There is a big difference between using LaTeX and MS Word to write a paper or make a poster. See my CW answer: http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/1894/929

Answer (score -4):

I think according to the rules software list questions are off topic since the are not "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"

That said, I think other sites (e.g., tex.se) have a history of allowing long list type questions.