# What is wrong with my question

Tags: discussion

A question, if I may, about my question about data backups and security [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10822/secure-backups-of-research), (which has now 5 upvotes, 1 downvote = 23 rep; 2 very full replies- also upvoted) based on my understanding that asking questions relating to [academic tools](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/are-questions-about-tools-on-topic) were okay.

It seems to have attracted a comment discussion about where to move it to - why is not alright here?

But if you decide to move it to ux.SE or wherever (another suggestion in the comments was superuser.SE), a practical question if I may - does it mean that the 23 rep that I have earned would be lost, especially as I am not a member of either of these sites? (seriously not sure how that works).

Comment: Well, that is now 2 downvotes for the question - so please, if you are going to migrate/delete/close the question, just do what you want to do. (I'll just stick to answering questions)

Answer (score 2):

Downvotes are not the same as close votes.

The issue is that you haven't done anything to make the question specific to this board. The situation you describe, **as you've described it**, could apply to anyone.

Asking, however, if universities offer tools to help with this, however, would make the question more relevant to this board.

Comment: so, it is going to be migrated, deleted or closed?
I have added in specific references to PhD and journal-research.

Comment: I can't guarantee anything—this is a community board, after all—but the fact that you already have several answers makes it an unlikely candidate for any of those fates.

Comment: I've also added a bit asking if _universities_ offer the services you're looking for. (For instance, in grad school, my school's IT service allowed us to back up our on-campus machines, and it turned out to be a lifesaver!)

Comment: fair enough.  A bit of background - the reference to my MSc submission was about when I was due to submit my thesis, I was right in the middle of the Queensland floods of 2011, and was in one of the worst hit areas - almost lost everything (including my own life).

Comment: I think this question does have academia-specific sides to it and thus is relevant for this site. For example, see my comment there on how publishing your work is, in a way, the "ultimate" backup.