# Big list question for reference managers

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness

This recent question on [reference managers and note taking](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/134435/up-to-date-toolbox-for-productivity-bibliography-and-academic-writing) has got me thinking again. I am on the record of [not liking big-list](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/749/big-list-questions) questions and really [not liking big-list software questions](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174/are-questions-on-software-on-topic). Questions about reference managers seem to keep coming up.

Do we want a big-list type question similar to this [LaTeX editors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) question and if so, what do we want the answers to look like?

Comment: I'd support this. One question is whether we want to permit judgements or comparisons, or whether we simply want a list. Relately, should it be a list in a single answer, or do we go for one solution per answer to allow for voting?

Answer (score 5):

Several times I've found big-list questions very useful, and I don't think there are enough *sound* reasons to ban them (whatever SE says).

For the format, *community wiki* and the shorter, the better: the relevant link, and a short description of what one likes about the product. Please, please let's not ask an essay for every suggestion.

Comment: +1 for wiki and short'n'sweet.