What to do when you disagree with close reason?
I'm relatively new here. Compared to Math Overflow, I've noticed that Academia has more frequent "tug of war" situations with closing and reopening questions. A question of mine was just closed as a shopping question but I think it's clear that it's not a shopping question, according to the definition of "shopping question". So, I would like to ask how to have my question reopened.
The link above (which I read before asking) defines a shopping question as:

A shopping question is a question that appears to seek help choosing,
finding or assessing an individual journal, an individual publisher,
an individual university, an individual academic program, an
individual field, an individual research topic, an individual funding
agency.
In most cases a shopping question can be identified by fulfilling one
of the following criteria: Naming one or more of the above would be an
answer to the question. Evaluating, criticising, or comparing one or
more of the above would be an answer to the question.

The definition goes on:

Note that questions about how to make such a choice in general – that do not involve naming any of the above – are not considered shopping questions and may be welcome here.

My question was seeking general resources for how to write an op-ed, which is of course something that academics sometimes do, but do not receive any training on. Seeking general resources is not like the list above that defines shopping questions. It seems to me that there are plenty of other questions seeking resources, that do not get closed. I would like some clarity on this issue. Thanks!

Agree on the tug-of-war (in general). We do have a high closure rate because many of the questions are manifestly off-topic -- but there are also many borderline questions that IMO should be left open. At any rate: to the title question, posting on meta is the right thing to do. I'm posting this as a comment in case you want to edit this meta question accordingly (e.g., "Should we reopen the question about ____?").

Also relevant: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/shopping-question-vs-resource-request

I haven't voted one way or the other on that post, but it did strike me as a possible "boat programming" question.

What kind of convinces me that this is indeed a shopping question is that the only two answers are basically link-only answers (which is also not the type of answer we want to have here, it is written somewhere, don't want to spend time looking for it). I actually was really torn and decided to skip it in the reopen queue when it came up because I wasn't sure how to decide. It is pretty borderline.

@Sursula Perhaps if the question had remained open, it might have attracted fuller answers. Closing a question quickly after it was asked because it has so far only attracted links as answers, does not seem reasonable to me personally.

@DavidWhite yeah, but the question wasn't closed quickly at all - from what I can see it was asked 9 days ago and closed only 2 days ago, so a full week has passed before it was closed, that is actually far from being closed quickly. Many closed questions are closed within hours of asking. And also the amount of new answers being posted after a week has passed is also quite low.

As this is one of the busiest weeks for professors (with end-of-semester meetings, final exams, grading, etc.), I think a week is a short time to stay open. I myself have two dozen tabs open that I need to get to, once I get through all the other tasks that have build up over the course of the semester.

@DavidWhite while you might be especially busy, others are not (its the middle of the semester here in Germany). But that nonwithstanding, this is just not how closing works. Noone thinks, "Ah this question might benefit from being left open for a while and if it didn't attract enough good anwers I'll come back in a week and vote to close!". People stumble accross questions (mainly the new ones) and decide that the question doesn't fit the scope and vote to close. Really, I think it is extremely long for a closed question to be left open for a whole week.

After a post-strike account deletion I don't have the rep to do close/open votes any longer. So, I wanted to take a brief moment here to endorse the thought that this question isn't a shopping question.
Some of the discussion in the comments involves whether to close questions which seem borderline on first reading, but on the basis that the subsequent answers fit the type of answers we expect from that close reason. I've been thinking about this reasoning off and on for some time, especially as it relates to our "opinion-based" close reason.
Just as a suggestion that I hope people find persuasive or at least entertain: I've come to personal criterion that closing a borderline question because of the answers it gets should only happen when the activity on the question overwhelms our other moderation tools.
As an example class that merits closure under this criterion: Most commonly this happens on borderline questions which hit the Hot Network Questions list. Perhaps the question seems okay at first, or borderline, but then the flood of HNQ activity spawns a ton of opinion-based or otherwise bad answers along with upvotes that the community here isn't big enough to regulate.
David's question is an example that I think would not merit closure this way. The answers that the question received were, to my mind, bad answers. They are short and link-only. But there are only two of them. If instead of voting to close we simply downvoted those, that seems to me a happier equilibrium.

Thanks for the support! As the question is closed, I cannot add what I learned over the past 13 days about writing op-eds. But, I can share that, I was able to successfully write one and get it published: https://www.nydailynews.com/2024/05/16/cooperation-can-end-violent-protests/

@DavidWhite Congrats on the publication! Where any of the learnings in any way related to you  being an academic or would apply especially to academics? Because if the don't (and I really don't mean that in any way negatively), this again would be an argument against the question being reopened, see Anyons comment on the question itself about boat programming. If you truly have any experiences to share uniquely valuable to academics, I will vote to reopen.

@Sursula Yes, absolutely. I even had discussions with the university communications team and the president of the university. But, these days I am extremely busy. I cannot promise to immediately take the time to write up all I learned as a self answer, and I don't really see the point, since clearly others are not that interested.
